# Click button to change select-element. Script only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, select

I'm trying write a script that allows a button click to change selected option in a select-element. This script is working in Chrome, but not in Firefox, how come?

http://jsfiddle.net/orjan/hsvp7pt8/

```
var searchOption = $('.container .select-box option:selected').text();
var searchValue = $('.container .select-box option:selected').val();

$('.container').each(function () {
    $(this).children('.select-box').attr('value', searchValue);
    if ($(this).find('.select-box option:selected').val() == 'articles') {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
$('.container .select-label').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');

    if ($(this).siblings('.select-box').children('option:selected').val() == 'option-a') {
        $(this).siblings('.select-box').children('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $(this).siblings('.select-box').children('option[value="option-b"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        var searchValue = $('.container .select-box option:selected').val();
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.select-box').children('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $(this).siblings('.select-box').children('option[value="option-a"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        var searchValue = $('.container .select-box option:selected').val();
    }
    $(this).siblings('.select-box').attr('value', searchValue);
});
```

Comment: just a little something but your if-else repeats the first and last action in each condition.  You can pull them out of that if-else to help you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.attr('selected')` to change the value of a menu. Just set the value of the menu directly with `$('.select-box').val('new-value')`.

```js
var searchOption = $('.container .select-box option:selected').text();
var searchValue = $('.container .select-box').val();

$('.container').each(function () {
    $(this).children('.select-box').attr('value', searchValue);
    if ($(this).find('.select-box option:selected').val() == 'articles') {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
$('.container .select-label').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    var select = $(this).siblings('.select-box');
    if (select.val() == 'option-a') {
        select.val('option-b');
    } else {
        select.val('option-a');
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
.container {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button class="select-label">Change</button>
    <select class="select-box">
        <option value="option-a" selected="selected">Example A</option>
        <option value="option-b">Example B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, note taken. Your code is a lot slimmer as well. Thanks